# Using a variable to name an Event Handler

Tags: winforms, event-handling

Updated 10 Nov 2022

I have the following code in a Winforms program:

```
void CreateCheckBoxes(Control parentControl, int left, int top, int lineSpace)
    {
        List<string> listVariables = new List<string>() { "AllowColumnReorder", "CaptureFocusClick", "ColScaleMode", "ColumnTracking", "RowTracking", "EnsureVisible", "FullRowSelect", "GridLines", "HideSelection", "HoverSelection", "IsFocused", "LabelEdit", "MultiSelect", "Scrollable", "VisualStyles" };
        
        foreach (string varName in listVariables)
        {
            CheckBox ctlTemp = new CheckBox { Name = "chk" + varName, Text = varName, Top = top, Left = left };
            parentControl.Controls.Add(ctlTemp);
            top += lineSpace;
        }

        chkAllowColumnReorder.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkAllowColumnReorder_CheckedChanged);
            //  The name 'chkAllowColumnReorder' does not exist in the current context

        }
```

It works to the extent that I can create as many CheckBoxes as I like based on the length of listVariables. However, I want the name of the CheckedChanged event handler to be based on the name of the control.

As well as my original question I now find I cannot refer to the CheckBox by the name provided in { Name = "chk" + varName, in the debugger a watch on "Name" returns the name of the form. I have not used this form of constructor before and am struggling to find any documentation on it. Can anybody help on this before I try to move on again please?

Is there a way to do this?

The code itself is produced by a small program where I just past in the names of variables from the main program and it produces the above, and all the vent handlers, which is an enormous time saver.

Comment: Not clear why you'd want that. You have a single event handler for all Controls. Then you just need to cast `sender` to `CheckBox` to handle the Control that raised the event. You probably don't want to have a handler for each Control you have in that list -- BTW, it appears you're not adding these Controls to the Parent instance passed as argument (unless you have omitted that part for some reason)

Comment: Each event will contain a line like:
containerListView1.Gridlines= chkBox.Checked;
So I need a separate event handler for each CheckBox.
I can get there if instead of using a loop to create the CheckBoxes I write the code so that there are several lines to create each CheckBox but it means longer source code. Perhaps that doesn't matter as it is machine produced.

Comment: Nope, you really don't need to. Instead of building just a *list of names*, build a side-by-side `Dictionary<CheckBox, Action<<CheckBox>` to associate an action to each CheckBox (e.g., `yourDictionary.Add(someCheckBox, (c) => containerListView1.Gridlines = c.Checked);`). Use the same delegate for all CheckBoxes, so in the event handler you can just write: `var chk = sender as CheckBox; yourDictionary[chk](chk);` and the action is triggered -- If you want an example, let me know

Comment: jimi
Many thanks:-)
I got completely carried away with this which is new to me. I have:

Dictionary<ContainerListView, Action<CheckBox>> m_Actions = new Dictionary<ContainerListView, Action<CheckBox>>();
m_Actions.Add(containerListView1, (c) => containerListView1.AllowColumnReorder = c.Checked);

Which works but I can't add more entries as the key "containerListView1" is already in the dictionary. I have been trying to set up a dictionary with Field or Property but there seems to be no such thing.
I need:
Dictionary<Field Value, Action<CheckBox>>
Can you help me move on please?

Comment: Why did you set a `ContainerListView` Type as Key? That's not what I wrote, which is instead `Dictionary<CheckBox, Action<<CheckBox>>`, designed to handle the `CheckedChanged` event of CheckBox instances, since what you need to evaluate is the `CheckBox.Checked` state when it changes -- Try that out, if you cannot get it to work, I'll post an example

Answer (score 0):

jimi - I've posted this as an answer as it's too long for a comment.

I ended up with:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<CheckBox>> m_Actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<CheckBox>>();
```

then loop through:

```
m_Actions.Add("chkAllowColumnReorder", (c) => containerListView1.AllowColumnReorder = c.Checked); etc.
```

and then:

```
void chkTemp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkTemp = ((CheckBox)sender);
            m_Actions[chkTemp.Name](chkTemp);
        }
```

This is completely new to me and I'm still not sure how (or why) it works but thank you very much for telling me about it - I can now paste variables in to my app's form and produce all the code to add controls to the app I need to test.

I did it because my heart sank at the thought of adding heaps of CheckBoxes to an app to test an ExtendeListView, in the end writing this to produce the code was much more interesting than the testing!